# Viewpager pass bundles between fragments

Tags: android, fragment, android-viewpager

I have a custom Viewpager in which it disables the touch events. So I have buttons 'Next' and 'Back' that control the viewpager. My question is how to pass data or bundles between the fragments in the viewpager. Normally it would work but sense the fragments are created even though they are not shown. That's because of the viewpager slide effect, it has to make the fragments ahead and before for the effect to work. So that means I can't use bundles since the fragment is already created. This is what I'm trying to do

Fragment 1 -> Fragment 2 -> Fragment 3

Fragment 1 is created and so is Fragment 2. When I press 'Next' Fragment 2 is shown. I want to pass a bundle to Fragment 3 when I press 'Next' again but Fragment 3 is already created so it won't work.

Another way I thought of is to call a method in each Fragment when the Viewpager sets it as its current Item.

Comment: Does the data need to be there at the time of creation, or is it fine if you pass it in just before displaying it?

Comment: @dmon It needs to be there just before displaying it. Like Fragment 2 will pass data right when I press 'Next', then Fragment 3 will be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create an interface that all of your fragments implement? This interface will have two methods: `getParameterData()` and `setParameterData()`. In your ViewPager, when they press next or previous, call `getParameterData()` on the current fragment, then call `setParameterData()` on the fragment to be displayed.

Comment: Wow I never thought about that, Thanks. One more thing. I noticed the Fragment has a method called setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser). That means when the Fragment is shown on the UI? When the Viewpager sets it as the current Item that method is called.

Comment: It might, I'm not sure. Have you tried overriding `onResume()`?

Comment: I used the onResume() but that gets called when the fragment is being created, which is off screen. So that didn't work. The setUserVisibleHint works perfectly for what I'm trying to do. I just check for isVisibleToUser boolean to see if it's visible on the screen.

Comment: could you please elaborate more on this. I am quite now to Java. like any example of some sort would do wonders

Answer (score 1):

You could share/pass your objects between fragments by holding them in the host activity.